# Plot Projects - exit geofence occasionally not triggering

Tags: android, ios, notifications, geolocation, geofencing

I'm using Plot Projects service to send geofencing notifications to users of iOS and Android application.

There seems to be a strange situation occasionally happening, that the notification linked to exit event on geofence does not get triggered. User enters the geofence, gets the enter notification (which is obviously a different notification than the exit one, but on the same geofence and with the same configuration except for the trigger and custom data), but after leaving the geofence the exit notification does not get triggered.

[I'm using Notification filter](https://www.plotprojects.com/documentation/#NotificationFilterDesignDecisions), so that the application, when receiving the "silent" notification, contacts the back-end (by making an API call), and depending on the response it shows the notification or ignores it.

Although the app logs are not accessible at the time when this happens, what can be deducted from the back-end logs is that the call has never reached the back-end API. This would mean that the "silent" notification has either never been triggered (meaning that the geofence exit was not recorded by Plot Projects SDK for some reason), or it has been triggered but for some reason not handled properly by the app. Having in mind that I do get proper exit notifications occasionally, I'm not sure an in-app problem could be causing this.

Looking at the Plot Projects dashboard, I see that enter notification has been triggered once, while the exit has not been triggered at all. This is on Notifications screen, under Sent column.

As noted, the only difference between configuration of enter and exit notifications is the Notification trigger setting (On entering as opposed to On exiting), and the custom data which is as follows:

```
{ "geofenceId" : "{geofenceid}", "action" : "enter" }
{ "geofenceId" : "{geofenceid}", "action" : "exit" }
```

Both notification also use segmentation, with the segmentation configuration being the same.

So, several questions here:

1. Has anyone encoutered a similar problem, and what has been the cause/solution?
2. When using notification filter, will the column "Sent" show the number of notifications that were shown to the user, or will it include count of "silent" notifications? (this may help deducting what the issue is)
3. Is there a reason in general why an exit notification may not trigger, depending on some specific conditions regarding the enter notification or other parameters? For example, 3G connection issue, network issue, etc.

Comment: Nebojsa Did you manage to found the solution>

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (1.15.0) has improved on this making enters and exits more consistent. I would recommend using that version when testing exit notifications.

1. Because of limitations related to efficiency and platform there will always be a small difference between the number of sent enter notifications and the number of exit notifications.
2. When notifications are filtered out using the notification filter they aren't included in the notification statistics. For silent notifications geotriggers may be more suitable, as those can be used silently while still showing up in the statistics.
3. Various reasons could prevent notifications from being sent, for example when the device is no longer able to determine its location.